# How to change <title> with delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know in jQuery 1.4.x there is a method delay(). We can use it like this:

```
$('#block').slideUp().delay(2000).slideDown();
```

and it works great. But i want to modify `document.title`, but this construction doesnt work:

```
$('title').html('New title 1').delay(2000).html('New title 2');
```

when you run this code title will be `New title 2` avoid any delay. How to fix it?

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a callback with [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp):

```
$('title').html('New title 1');

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('title').html('New title 2');
}, 2000);
```

`$.fn.delay` puts a delay in the animation queue.  It does not delay the running script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `.delay()` and `.queue()`, you can do this:

```
$('title').html('New title 1').delay(2000)
          .queue(function() { $(this).html('New title 2'); });
```

Though `setTimeout` like stranger has seems simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to call $(this).dequeue() if you are going with the Nick Cravers approach, otherwise your queue will stall all others.

```
$(this).val("newTitle1")
        .effect("pulsate", { times: 3 }, "slow")
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).val("newtitle 2")
            .effect("pulsate", {times: 1}, "slow");
        $(this).dequeue(); //dont forget to do this
                });
```